# How to show selected last 30 days value in static range by default in react-date-range npm when page is load

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

1. I am using react-date-range node module. i want to select the default last 90 days side bar option when react component is load.

Image url is [enter image description here][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/snCr8.png

here is the code below which i am using.

I have create the custom side for selecting the default date range direct. want to select default any date range.

```
import {
  DateRangePicker,
  defaultStaticRanges,
  createStaticRanges
} from "react-date-range";

import {
  addDays,
  endOfDay,
  startOfDay,
  startOfMonth,
  endOfMonth,
  addMonths,
  startOfWeek,
  endOfWeek,
  startOfYear,
  endOfYear,
  addYears
} from "date-fns";

import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css";
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";

const defineds = {
  startOfWeek: startOfWeek(new Date()),
  endOfWeek: endOfWeek(new Date()),
  startOfLastWeek: startOfWeek(addDays(new Date(), -7)),
  endOfLastWeek: endOfWeek(addDays(new Date(), -7)),
  startOfToday: startOfDay(new Date()),
  startOfLastSevenDay: startOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -7)),
  startOfLastThirtyDay: startOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -30)),
  startOfLastNintyDay: startOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -90)),
  endOfToday: endOfDay(new Date()),
  startOfYesterday: startOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -1)),
  endOfYesterday: endOfDay(addDays(new Date(), -1)),
  startOfMonth: startOfMonth(new Date()),
  endOfMonth: endOfMonth(new Date()),
  startOfLastMonth: startOfMonth(addMonths(new Date(), -1)),
  endOfLastMonth: endOfMonth(addMonths(new Date(), -1)),
  startOfYear: startOfYear(new Date()),
  endOfYear: endOfYear(new Date()),
  startOflastYear: startOfYear(addYears(new Date(), -1)),
  endOflastYear: endOfYear(addYears(new Date(), -1))
};

const initialState = {
  selection: {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: addDays(new Date(), 30),
    key: "selection"
  },
  compare: {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: addDays(new Date(), 30),
    key: "compare"
  }
};

const sideBarOptions = () => {
  const customDateObjects = [
    {
      label: "Lifetime",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfToday,
        endDate: defineds.endOfToday
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Today",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfToday,
        endDate: defineds.endOfToday
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Last 7 Days",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfLastSevenDay,
        endDate: defineds.endOfToday
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Last 30 Days",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfLastThirtyDay,
        endDate: defineds.endOfToday
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Last 90 Days",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfLastNintyDay,
        endDate: defineds.endOfToday
      })
    },
    {
      label: "This Week",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfWeek,
        endDate: defineds.endOfWeek
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Last Week",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfLastWeek,
        endDate: defineds.endOfLastWeek
      })
    },
    {
      label: "This Month",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfMonth,
        endDate: defineds.endOfMonth
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Last Month",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfLastMonth,
        endDate: defineds.endOfLastMonth
      })
    },
    {
      label: "This Year",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOfYear,
        endDate: defineds.endOfYear
      })
    },
    {
      label: "Last Year",
      range: () => ({
        startDate: defineds.startOflastYear,
        endDate: defineds.endOflastYear
      })
    }
  ];

  return customDateObjects;
};

function RangeCalender() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const sideBar = sideBarOptions();

  const staticRanges = [
    // ...defaultStaticRanges,
    ...createStaticRanges(sideBar)
  ];
  const handleSelect = ranges => {
    console.log(ranges);
    setState({ ...state, ...ranges });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <DateRangePicker
          showSelectionPreview={true}
          ranges={[state.selection, state.compare]}
          onChange={handleSelect}
          months={2}
          minDate={addDays(new Date(), -900)}
          maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 900)}
          direction="horizontal"
          //scroll={{ enabled: true }}
          showMonthAndYearPickers={true}
          staticRanges={staticRanges}
          inputRanges={[]}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by setting your selection state as below:

```
//import subDays from date-fns

const [ state, setState ] = useState([
    {
        startDate: subDays(new Date(), 90),
        endDate: new Date(),
        key: 'selection'
    }
]);
```

I've made mine worked here: https://pastebin.com/NdYs3hda.